# Convolutional Autoencoder feature learning

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am training a **convolutional autoencoder** on my own dataset. After training, the network is able to reconstruct the test images from the dataset quite well.

I am now taking the intermediate representation(**1648**-dim) from the encoder network and trying to cluster the feature vectors into 17(known upfront) different classes using a **GMM soft clustering**. However, the clusters are really bad and it is not able to cluster the images into its respective categories.

I am using **sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture** package for clustering with a regularization of 0.01 and 'full' covariance_type.

**My question**: Why do you think that the reconstruction is very decent but the clustering is quite bad? Does it mean the intermediate features learned by the network is not adequate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets revert the question - why do you think it should have any meaning? You are using **clustering**, which is just **arbitrary method of splitting into groups** yet you expect it will discover **classes**. Why would it do it? There is literally nothing forcing model to do so, and it is probably modeling completely different things (like patches of images, textures etc.). In general you should **never** expect clustering to solve the problem of some arbitrary labeling, this is not what clustering is for. To give you more perspective here - you have images, which come from say 10 categories (like cats, dogs etc.), and you ask:

- why clustering in the feature space does not recover classes?

Note that equally valid questions would be:

- why clustering in the features space does not divide images to "redish", "greenish" and "blueish"?
- why clustering in the features space does not divide images by the size of the object on the image?
- why clustering in the features space does not divide images by the country it is from?

There are exponentially many labelings to be assigned to each dataset, and **nothing** in your training uses any labels (autoencoding is unsupervised, clustering is unsupervised) so expecting that the result will magically guess which of so many labellings you have in mind is simply a wild guess, and the fact it does not do so means nothing. It is neither good nor bad. (Lets also ignore at this point how good can GMM be with ~1700 dimensional space. )

If you want a model to perform some task you have to give it a chance, train it to solve it. If you want to see if features learned are enough to recover categories then learn **a classifier** on them.

Comment: I have fine-tuned the network with labeled images but it didn't improve the situation at all